A term for a person who sees a message then reply for some other matter instead of addressing what was needed to be addressed?
For a video I sent to a group.
My sister replied by tagging the video and said something about my profile picture which I found rude instead of addressing the video and saying something genuine about it.

@xanne The question is asking for a term to describe a person who doesn't respond in the expected manner. It seems like a standard SWR question to me.

I don't think there is a term for the person. "She made an irrelevant comment".

You want an adjective or a noun? Give an example sentence. In general there are lots of concepts that could apply (many of which are covered by existing posts) - being unhelpful, selfishness, changing the subject (for various reasons), saying a random non-sequitur, etc. But probably the best solution is just to talk to your sister.

See also What do you call an answer that disagrees with the question? Where someone thinks that the question is uncalled for (often contentious in itself) or badly worded etc, they may address the question in a frame challenge rather than giving what some would see as the sought-for answer.

Most of the answers to the other question, as well as the one answer posted on this page, assume that the respondent is aware of what the real subject matter is, and then deliberately avoids it, perhaps due to its being somehow difficult. These days, however, what the OP describes often seems to be due to the respondent's being too rushed or unfocused to even consider what the real subject matter is, and then distracted by something tangential.

It's called evading the question. No name for the perpetrator, other than adjectives that describe why they are evading. Like 'feckless'.
